# How to configure akka producer to negotiate TLS v1.2

Tags: java, ssl, akka

My Java application uses akka 2.3.12 on OpenJDK 7. How do I configure my UntypedProducerActor to use TLS v1.2 when connecting to an external HTTPS URI?

I tried setting -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv.1 in java command line, but it didn't seem to have any effect. ClientHello still uses TLSv1.

The code is simple:

```
public class ProvisioningResponseWriter extends UntypedProducerActor {
    private final String uri;

    public ProvisioningResponseWriter(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri
    }

    @Override
    public String getEndpointUri() {
        return this.uri;
    }
}
```

As an example, if uri is **https**://our_customer.com, this actor would try to set up a secured connection to the server with TLSv1.0. But our customer requires that we use TLSv1.2.

I learn that Java 7 will use TLSv1.0 by default, and have tried to use -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 but that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about where and how ssl is used? Some code samples would be great to understand what your app does and where is your problem.

Comment: Added some code and description per Vanya's suggestion

Comment: dig into this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257501/which-tls-version-does-netty-support-tls-1-0-1-1-or-1-2

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry sounds like the best option is to upgrade to JDK 8. However, I was hoping for a programmatic way to force the actor to use TLSv1.2.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be looking for the configuration that controls the underlying platform TLS implementation via `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2`.

Afaik `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` controls the protocol used by Java clients which obtain https connections through use of the HttpsURLConnection class or via URL.openStream() operations so maybe that's not the case of whatever http client implementation there is for `akka 2.3.12`?